# Use desktop icons in Debian 10

Tags: debian, gnome, nautilus

Debian 10 (Buster) uses GNOME 3.30, which again can use icons on the desktop. To achieve this, I understand that one needs to make a setting that GNOME uses Nautilus to manage the desktop.

I searched in dconf-editor, Optimierungen and Einstellungen (no idea what they're called in English), bus was unable to find such a setting.

Where can I find this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ll find the relevant setting using `dconf-editor`, in `org.gnome.desktop.background`, as `show-desktop-icons`:

[image: Screenshot of <code>dconf-editor</code> showing the <code>show-desktop-icons</code> details]

The setting doesn’t work for me though, so I’m still using [the Desktop Icons extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1465/desktop-icons/).

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, re-installed the extension I had already dumped.

Answer (score 3):

Nautilus desktop support has been removed:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/158#instructions.
But they left the setting.

These are at least 3 solutions:

1. Use `nemo-desktop` instead, `nemo` is a fork from `nautilus`.
   Quote from the above link:

> 1. Install nemo from your distribution's repositories. On Fedora, enter
>    this command on the Terminal application:
>
> `sudo dnf install nemo`
>
> 2. Open a text editor and copy the following text into a new empty file:
>
> ```
>     [Desktop Entry]
>     Type=Application
>     Name=Nemo
>     Comment=Start Nemo desktop at log in
>     Exec=nemo-desktop
>     OnlyShowIn=GNOME;
>     AutostartCondition=GSettings org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons
>     X-GNOME-AutoRestart=true
>     NoDisplay=true
> ```
>
> 3. Save the text file as
>    `~/.config/autostart/nemo-autostart-with-gnome.desktop`
>
> And that's it! Next time you log in, nemo will automatically display
> icons over the desktop background. If you don't want to log out, you
> can also manually start it using the Alt+F2 prompt to run nemo-desktop
>
> Optional step: In case you want Nemo to behave more similarly to
> nautilus desktop layout, you can enable the setting running this
> command on the terminal:
>
> `gsettings set org.nemo.desktop use-desktop-grid false`

(On Debian use `apt install nemo`).

On my Debian 10 system I can see that the `AutostartCondition=GSettings org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons` line on the .desktop file doesn't change color as the other on `gedit` (text editor).
I need to remove that part to use it.

2. Use an extension for desktop icons, like this for example: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1465/desktop-icons/.
3. You can use the `desktopfolder` package.

There are also `idesk` and `rox-filer` https://wiki.debian.org/Openbox#Desktop_icons.

I tried `idesk` on gnome it works bad an you have to manually set the icons.
It doesn't reflect the desktop folder.

Comment: For those who recently migrated to Debian 12, the only working solution seems to be the installation of `nemo`.